# EasyMock - override an object creation

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock

How can I override an object creation inside a method?

```
public class ClassToTest {
    public Object testMethod() {
        ... code ...
        Object result;
        try {
            result = new ClassToMock(someParam).execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle error
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

How can my test override the "execute" method of ClassToMock? I will be happy for code examples with EasyMock. I want to test "testMethod", something like:

```
@Test
public void testMethodTest(){
    ClassToTest tested = new ClassToTest();
    // Mock ClassToMock somehow
    tested.testMethod();
    // Verify results
}
```

Comment: Sorry Works around the clock for production deadline...

Comment: No need to feel sorry! Sometimes one just forgets that questions were already answered and could be accepted. Happened to me, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply spoken: that doesn't work.

You can't mock calls to **new** (using EasyMock. It is possible using frameworks like PowerMock(ito) or JMockit though).

But the better way: use *dependency injection* in order to pass already created objects into your class under test.

To be more precise: if your class really doesn't need any other objects to work, then a test would more look like

```
 @Test
 public void testFoo() {
    ClassToTest underTest = new ClassToTest(...)
    underTest.methodToTest();
    assertThat( ... )
```

In other words: in order to test your class, you simply instantiate it; then you call methods on it; and you use asserts to check the expected states of it.

See [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) for excellent (although a bit lengthy) explanations on what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible to override methods if the method of the class is not marked as `final`

```
try {
    ClassToMock mock = new ClassToMock(someParam){
        public Object execute(){ //Such that your method is public
            //If you want to call back to the pure method
            //super.execute()

            //Do override things here
        }
    };
    result = mock.execute();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: I want to do a unit test to "testMethod", so when do I call it? How does "testMethod" can use the mock object instead of the real one? sorry for basics stuff. I'm a beginner with Java unit tests.

Comment: You can use [JUnit](http://junit.org/junit4/) and add `@Test` annotation on the top of the method.

Comment: How does "testMethod" can use the mock object instead of the real one?

Comment: I don't know `mock objects`

Comment: May be you can search around to find your answer

Answer (score -1):

It is possible with Powermock. Using powermock, you can mock 'new' operator as well

```
ClassToMock mock = PowerMock.createMock(ClassToMock.class);
PowerMock.expectNew(ClassToMock.class, parameterValues).andReturn(mock);
PowerMock.replayAll();
```

For more details please refer this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/using-powermock-mock)