# How to access and set object of i18n object or any private object inside class using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, internationalization, superclass, easymock

1) Question: 
I want to access any class field through reflection.?
(Field). i.e. `getDeclaredField("i18n").`

So should **"Field"** considered as String, Int variable, Local variable.
Also object considered in Field. If so how to access object through reflection?

```
Class X{
    private I18nUtils i18n; // object.
    X(){
     i18n.getText("--some string--");
    }
}
```

How to access and set i18n object.

Comment: *"should "Field" considered as String, Int variable"* `Field` is a class representing a *field* of another class, as the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) says: *A Field provides information about, and dynamic access to, a single field of a class or an interface.* --- That field can be of type `String`, `int`, or any other valid Java type. It certainly cannot be a *local variable*, so those aren't *fields*.

Comment: *"how to access object through reflection?"* Use the `Field` object returned by `getDeclaredField("i18n")`. Look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#method.summary) to see if any of the methods may be what you need. *Hint:* It's the one documented with: *Returns the value of the field represented by this `Field`, on the specified object.*

Comment: Look Once : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58509820/easymock-throwing-nullpointerexception-due-to-not-accessible-to-parent-class-p